# The specified blob does not exist - Download Azure Storage File From Android

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I know there are similar questions like this one but none of them worked for me. **I am trying to download a file from Azure storage**. But I am getting an error and the error message is **The specified blob does not exist**. But the blob does exist and my connection string is also valid. I am sharing my code below.
It would be helpful if someone can help me out.

Code:

```
public void downloadFile(ShowContentInfo showContentInfo){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    executor.execute(() ->{
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
        try {
            String dir = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/LmsContents/";
            if (!dt.file.folderExists(dir)) {
                dt.file.createFolder(dir);
            }
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(CONNECTION_STRING);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("containerName");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference("rblobName");
            File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/LmsContents/" + showContentInfo.getContentTitle());
            blockBlob.downloadToFile("/storage/emulated/0/Download/LmsContents/" + showContentInfo.getContentTitle());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler.post(() -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Please double check the existence of container name and blob name and also the storage account.

Comment: Same thought from me, because code seems pretty much ok for me. Let's see what others' opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that your `blob file` is not directly under the `container`. Please check in azure storage via azure portal, see if the `blob file` is under some `subfolders` within the `container`.

If yes(for example, the blob file is `b.txt`, container name is `container111`, and subfolder name is `sub111`), then you should change this line of code

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference("rblobName");
```

to

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference("sub111\b.txt");
```

And also, please check the connection string is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought. I found my mistakes by following your suggestion and accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the folder references it seems folder structure which you are providing incorrect. Just see while debugging url is correct or not .